# Sliding to change tabs in Chrome

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, chrome-for-android, touchscreen

When I opened Chrome for the first time on my tablet, it told me (among other things) that I can switch tabs by sliding on the side of the screen.....have since tried, and it did not work.

What am I doing wrong? Is there some setting that needs to be tweaked, or am I just that bad at swiping a touchscreen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really sure about the tablet version, but in the current mobile version you need to swipe on URL bar.